# site name or sitename.com in page title?

Tags: seo, keyword, page-title

Just thinking about my page titles and wondering which one to have

keyword | keyword | site name

or

keyword | keyword | sitename.com

Would the sitename.com work better if it was an online only company?

---

OK great thanks guys, I think to keep it consistent I am going to use 'site name' as renaming everything to .com wont work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMO it's all how  you want to be perceived. Amazon includes the .com in their title tags, but Ebay, Netflix and Home Depot do not. Personally, I just use the company name without the .com at the end of the title tag but I don't believe there is any negative repercussions for including it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, When you put in Sitename.com, you already have your site name ( I am guessing). 
Also, try to be  consistent and stick to either one. The one you chose should be the one users are most familiar with.

In any case, you want users to come to your website, so give more importance to sitename.com . Once they are on your site, then you can display the name of your business.

Comment: I haven't started the site yet, and the company doesn't exist so there are no customers so far... it has a very unique name so it wont be confused with anything and it will also be online only... given that its a random unique name should I not bother using the company name in there and concentrate on the more competitive keywords, or is it good to boost the name with | site name in the title to start off with? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Personally would not bother with the `.com`, especially if you have a unique name. Brand yourself with the name and save having to add `.com` to everything.

Think of all the established web businesses and recent web upstarts. Are they known as `example.com` or things like Quora, Pinterest, Google or Bing.